# Using base_path and directory variables in twig template

Tags: theming, media

I'm creating a Drupal 8 theme. I have overriden the menu.html.twig... and I need to add an image to the first menu item.

In the page.html.twig I have used `{{ base_path ~ directory }}` to get the url of image like this:

```
<img class="logo_inder" src="{{ base_path ~ directory }}/img/logo-inder.png" />
```

But I'm trying to insert an image in themes/(my_theme)/templates/menu.html.twig like this:

```
<img src="{{ base_path ~ directory }}/img/inicio-icono.png" />
```

But is in this file, I can't print these variables:

```
{{ directory }}
{{ base_path }}
```

or

```
{{ base_path ~ directory }}
```

How can I print the base URL for use in my image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can expose the `base_path` variable to all you templates by implementing `hook_preprocess()` in your theme `.theme` file.

e.g.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess(array &$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['base_path'] = base_path();
}
```

where `mytheme` is the machine name of your theme.

You can use `{{ active_theme_path() }}` to get the path to the active theme.

Comment: Thank you... the active_theme_path() worked perfectly to print yhe path of the active theme

But the base_path didnt work... it is not printing anything... I rebuilded cache

.... Do you know why drupal doesnt have this "base_path" variable by default in all the *.html.twig files under the template folder in themes? it should be a nice improvement... how can we suggest that?

Comment: To suggest new things or report bugs just open a new issue on drupal.org for the Drupal project. The preprocess hook works, are you sure you named it correctly after your  theme?

Comment: I'm trying to print it using the tag {{ base_path }} but is not working...  that could be the mistake?
I also tried to implement it in the function. "mytheme_preprocess_menu(&$variables, $hook, $info) " but still not working

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help without more background information. if your theme is called `my_theme` then the function should be `my_theme_preprocess_menu()` and for my example `my_theme_preprocess()`. We use this method to expose the variable everywhere and it works

Comment: thanks for your help... I have a clue about my problem...
If I use the base_path before the macro... it prints the value of the base path...
`{{ base_path }}
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level, base_path) %}`

but if I print it after the macro... it doesnt print anything!
`{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level, base_path) %}
{{ base_path }}`

Comment: I found the answer in [link](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html)
**You can pass the whole context as an argument by using the special _context variable.**
Thanks!!! @zerolab

Comment: Thanks to this answer, I was able to find a workaround to point to a parent theme directory, and will just leave this comment here,  be careful with using `{{ directory }}` and `{{ active_theme_path() }}` in a theme that you intend to use as a base theme and create sub-themes for:  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277278