# {{ directory }} in Twig template in base theme breaks subtheme

Tags: 8, theming

Given a base theme called `parent` that is a child of `stable`, and a sub-theme called `child` whose base theme is `parent`,  a Twig template implemented in the `parent` theme renders the wrong value for `{{ directory }}` variable.

1. In the parent theme, add a node.html.twig template with the following content:

   ```
   {# contents of parent/templates/node.html.twig #}
   file is themes/custom/parent/templates/content/node.html.twig<br>
   directory is: {{ directory }}
   ```

   Leave `node.html.twig` unimplemented in child theme, so that it inherits from parent.
2. Set default theme to `child`.
3. Visiting node/1 will print:

   ```
   file is themes/custom/parent/templates/content/node.html.twig
   directory is themes/custom/child
   ```

In theory, step 3 should produce a value of `themes/custom/parent` for the directory variable, otherwise, how can you depend on that variable to reference URLs of additional assets from the parent theme?

In actuality, `{{ directory }}` is acting exactly like `{{ active_theme_path() }}`.

As I understand it, this basically means that you cannot use `{{ directory }}` to reference any static assets in a base or parent theme, such as the path to an image icon, or using the `{{ source() }}` Twig function to insert an inline SVG.  In my case, I'm trying to do just this:

`{{ source(directory ~ '/images/svg/resources.svg') }}`

But I get: **Twig_Error_Loader: Template "themes/custom/child/images/svg/resources.svg" is not defined.**  Obviously, that file only exists in the parent theme.

Possibly this should be filed as a bug on drupal.org but wanted to check here first if this is already known and/or to award some karma points for a successful workaround.

**Update:**

My current workaround is to implement hook_preprocess() and set a global template variable called `parent_theme_path` that points to the parent theme path.

```php
// @file parent.theme
/**
 * Prepares global variables for all templates.
 */
function parent_preprocess(&$variables) {
  $handler = \Drupal::service('theme_handler');
  $variables['parent_theme_path'] = $handler->getTheme('parent')->getPath();
}
```

```
{# @file parent/templates/node.html.twig #}
{{ source( parent_theme_path ~ 'images/svg/resources.svg') }}
```

Comment: I opened up an issue on Drupal.org for this https://www.drupal.org/i/3049414

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this:

```
{{ source('@parent/../images/svg/resources.svg') }}
```

where `@parent` is the name of the parent theme. `@parent` references to the `templates` folder, so `@parent/../` was added to go to the root directory of your theme.